# Nodejs socket Emitting for larger Transmission

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm Trying to show progress bar in angular when inserting bulk csv data for more than 60,000 records. For that i used socket.io for emitting , when each individual records gets saved in db an socket is emitted.The Problem is socket gets disconnected for more than 60,000 emits.
i have used the below code

```
let io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
io.emit('update_'+ _id, 'success');
```

Socket gets disconnected when emitting more than 60,000 times

Comment: Why are you emitting that often? Why not every 1000th step or something? Seems like a bad design to me tbh.

Comment: @MauriceNino I want to show progress for each and every Record when added in Db and for also displaying progress count